# fully working vba doesn't run on other machines

Tags: excel, vba

I developed some vba codes that nicely work on my machine (win7, excel2010-32bit). I tested the same workbook on other machines to ensure compatibility and **sometimes** on machine that match or doesn't my configuration, some functions seems to fail. Even in those case, sometimes a simple restart of the workbook seems to solve the issue.

One of the guilty functions is, as instance:

```
Worksheets("home").Range("A:E").NumberFormat = "@"
```

That raises the error:

> unable to set the NumberFormat Property of the Range class: 1004.

I am struggling with this hardly replicable issue and I don't know how to handle it, since I don't understand the source of the problem.

Comment: I assume the additional `.` after `Range` and befor `("A:E")` is a typo, right?

Comment: yes, the code was on a non-accessible machine so I copied it manually. sorry

Comment: You will have to provide bit more of your code. Maybe the above line is not executing on your machine because it's wrapped round some logic.. which would be more of a logical issue. As @Storax pointed, that code will throw the error you have shown

Comment: This error may happen if you have a protected sheet.

Comment: I am sure the code ran, 'cause it is triggered by the pression of a button.
Effectively the sheet is protected: how that can trigger the error?

Comment: FunThomas is right, The line `Worksheets("home").Range("A:E").NumberFormat = "@"` will just trigger the error above.

Comment: @AndreaGiordano Did you even try this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390969/11167163) ? It might Answer to your question : Effectively the sheet is protected: how that can trigger the error? . If the Sheet Is protected and you want to format Cell you must Allow it.. So please have a look to my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57390969/11167163). If this doesn't help please give some feedbacks so I can **Improve** My Answer..

Comment: @Dorian I am testing, It is not easy to find people that allow to test your work on their pc.

Comment: I am puzzled because at the workbook_open I have explicitily set the protection on UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Comment: @AndreaGiordano UserInterfaceOnly = true **Only** allow macro to run it does not allow sheet to be modified...

Comment: @AndreaGiordano Please have a look to The **Edit** Of my answer I tried to explain what exactly does UserinterfaceOnly, Hope it helps